# Sending ether directly from metamask to fallback function

Tags: solidity, web3js, metamask, dapps, ethereum-wallet-dapp

I want to send some amount of ether to a smart contract from *metamask* (without using web3) and want it to perform some specific tasks based on that amount. For example, if I send *0.9* ether, I want it to set a variable named *planid* to *1101* in the fallback function. The following piece of code is from my contract:

```
 function() external payable {
    
    if (msg.sender == bank_owner) {
        emit AdminDeposit(msg.value, bank_owner);
        //invest(msg.value, msg.sender, plan_id, _referrer);
    } else {
        address _referrer = bytesToAddress(msg.data);
        _init(msg.sender, msg.value, _referrer);
    }
}

function _init(address payable _investor, uint256 _investValue, address _referrer) private {
    bool doInvest = true;
    if (_investValue == PLAN_PRICE[0]) {
        planid = 1101;
    }
    else if (_investValue == PLAN_PRICE[1]) {
        planid = 1102;
    }
    else if (_investValue == PLAN_PRICE[2]) {
        planid = 1103;
    }
    else if (_investValue == PLAN_PRICE[3]) {
        planid = 1104;
    } 
    else{
        doInvest = false;
        emit TestEvent(planid);
    }

    if (doInvest == true){
        invest(_investValue, _investor, planid, _referrer);
    }else
    {
        revert("Incorrect value sent!");
    }
}
```

In the above piece of code, If someone (other than bank owner which is already defined in the constructor) send *0.9* ether from *metamask* to the contract (directly), the *_init()* function will be called. I expect that *else* part of the second if statement does not executes. However, it executes and transaction fails.

When I replace *revert()* with something else, everything is ok. I was wondering if you help me with this case. Thanks.

Comment: I think it's something related to the ```_referrer``` variable. Can you attach the full contract code so we can test?

Comment: @MiroslavNedelchev Thank you for your comment. As stated by by alireza, the problem was due to the low value of gasLimit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transaction is failed because the gas limit you allocated in Metamask is less than what required. When we compare, `_init()` consumes gas more than `revert()`. So, you need to set gas limit of transcartion as much as necessary in the part indicated in the photo:

[image]

Good Luck.

Comment: I really appreciate your assistant. The problem solved.

Comment: @NimsShiri, You're welcome. So, please mark the answer to if another has this question it can find the correct answer easily.

Comment: Please send me a message through email for an industrial collaboration. Sorry for asking here. I couldn't find your contact information. My email: nimashiri2012@gmail.com.